# React property disappears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues with a passed down prop. I'm trying to render an array of objects in a list. However, the prop returns the results, and then immediately turns it to 'undefined'. Open dev tools to see result in console.

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { SearchBar } from '../SearchBar/SearchBar.js';
import { SearchResults } from '../SearchResults/SearchResults.js';
import { Playlist } from '../Playlist/Playlist.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchResults: [
        {
          id: 2011,
          name: 'What Makes A Man',
          artist: 'Man As Machine',
          album: 'Nothing but a thing'
        },
        {
          id: 2056,
          name: 'Pushpin',
          artist: 'Man As Machine',
          album: 'Patterns'
        },
        {
          id: 2099,
          name: 'Zombie',
          artist: 'Man As Machine',
          album: 'Patterns'
        }
      ],
      playlistName: ''
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
        <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
            <Playlist />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the first child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchResults.css';

import { Tracklist } from '../Tracklist/Tracklist.js';

export class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <Tracklist tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The destination child component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Tracklist.css';

import { Track } from '../Track/Track.js';

export class Tracklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderTrackList() {
    let properties = this.props.tracks;
    if (properties === undefined){
      return <h3>Sorry, we found no results</h3>
    } else {
      properties.forEach( track => {
        console.log(track);
        return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />;
      })
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.renderTrackList()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have attached the other components just for clarity. They are as follows:
playlist:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Playlist.css';

import { Tracklist } from '../Tracklist/Tracklist.js';

export class Playlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input defaultValue='New Playlist'/>
          <Tracklist />
        <a className="Playlist-save">SAVE</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

searchBar:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SearchBar.css';

export class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchBar">
        <input placeholder="Enter A Song, Album, or Artist" />
        <a>SEARCH</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Track:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Track.css';

export class Track extends React.Component {
  renderAction (isRemoval) {
    if (this.props.isRemoval){
      return <a className="Track-action" onClick={this.removeTrack}>-</a>
    } else {
      return <a className="Track-action" onClick={this.addTrack}>+</a>
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="Track">
        <div className="Track-information">
          <h3>{this.props.track.name}</h3>
          <p>{this.props.track.artist} | {this.props.track.album}</p>
        </div>
        <a className="Track-action">{this.renderAction}</a>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Please note that this is still a work in progress. So a lot of the detail and event handlers still need to be programmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```js
properties.forEach( track => {
    console.log(track);
    return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />;
})
```

write

```js
return properties.map( track => {
    console.log(track);
    return <Track key={track.id} track={track} />;
})
```

OR

`.map` without `return`

```js
return properties.map( track => (
    <Track key={track.id} track={track} />
))
```

Comment: @TheDarkNord would you mark the answer as complete? It'd help others

Comment: @Sung Kim . Done. had to wait 10 mins. Thanks again community!

Comment: @Amberlamps hey I edited your answer and added doing .map without return. Please let me know if that make sense